# How to send AT from Android device through USB into other Vonage device or phone device?

Tags: java, android, usb, at-command, modem

I'm trying to send AT commands for caller id through USB cable to my **Vonage** device. I tried this [LINK](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/how-to-talk-to-modem-commands-t1471241), but not getting success. I can't able to send Query Commands. Anyone can tell me please how to send AT commands via usb cable.